# Проблема с декоратором callback_query_handler в python / telegram

Tags: python, telebot, python-telegram-bot

недавно начал изучать разработку телеграм ботов на пайтоне с помощью телебот, возникла проблема с кодом, именно с обработкой результатов нажатия кнопок, вот сам код:

````
def start(message):
    mess = f'Поехали <b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>, введи /go'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess, parse_mode='html')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['go'])
def go(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Кнопка 1', callback_data='1'))
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Кнопка 2', callback_data='2'))
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Кнопка 3', callback_data='3'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Сообщение', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
    if call.data == '1':
        markup_reply = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        markup_reply.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Кнопка A', callback_data='a'))
        bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, 'Выбери кнопку', reply_markup=markup_reply)
    elif call.data == '2':
        markup_reply = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        markup_reply.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Кнопка B', callback_data='b'))
        bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, 'Выбери кнопку', reply_markup=markup_reply)
    elif call.data == '3':
        markup_reply = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        markup_reply.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Кнопка C', callback_data='c'))
        bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, 'Выбери кнопку', reply_markup=markup_reply)
    

#Вот здесь после обработки второго хэндлера, он должен слать сообщение, допустим "123",
я так понимаю что он обрабатывает предыдущий хэндлер с кнопками 1,2,3,
не приступая к хэндлеру с кнопками А,В,С, каким образом это исправить? 
@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
def answer(call):

       if call.data == 'a':
            bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, '123')



@bot.message_handler()
def get_user_text(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи корректную команду')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас первый хендлер перехватывает, все callback-сообщения. Вам следует либо изменить лямбду с `lambda call: True` на отслеживание конкретных команд, например `lambda call: call.data == '1' or call.data == '2'`.

Либо использовать функция `register_next_step_handler` и изменить  код.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
    if call.data == '1':
        markup_reply = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        markup_reply.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Кнопка A', callback_data='a'))
        bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, 'Выбери кнопку', reply_markup=markup_reply)
    elif call.data == '2':
        markup_reply = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        markup_reply.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Кнопка B', callback_data='b'))
        bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, 'Выбери кнопку', reply_markup=markup_reply)
    elif call.data == '3':
        markup_reply = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        markup_reply.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Кнопка C', callback_data='c'))
        bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, 'Выбери кнопку', reply_markup=markup_reply)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(call, answer1)


def answer1(call):
    if call.data == 'a':
        bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, '123')
```